# Database design with optional relationships

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate, relational-database

I have to modify my schema because new entities must be added.
This is the schema:

ER diagram
[image]

Table diagram

[image]
Outside the rectangle shape there is the actual database where each user can have one or more Applications.
There are several roles: Admin, User etc... Admin can see all applications instead the other roles can use only some applications.

Now I have an if in my code in which I check if the user is Admin or not and so show up all applications or only those linked.
I have to add several up-levels on applications up to Power. 
The roles will change: Admin, Zone Admin, Site Admin, Application Admin etc....
Admin can use all the applications, Zone admin all the application of a specific Zone, Site admin all the application for a specific site and so forth.

For example:

John(Admin roles) selects Power, then Zone, the Site and Fleet and uses all the Applications

Peter(Zone admin) selects Site then the Fleet and use all the Applications
...

Tim (user) can see only some fleets and so the page for power, zone and site selection are avoided.

What is the best way to create this system? I thought to use optional relationships between user and Power, User and Zone and so forth.

Comment: Start by using a DB modelling tool (like *DBDesigner for MySQL*) and not that funny diagram style you use now.

Comment: juergen d, that "funny diagram style" is actually proper entity-relationship diagram notation. DBDesigner produces table diagrams, not ER diagrams. Does it support ternary and higher relationships like the ER model does?

Comment: Why ER diagram is funny? I thought it was enough, anyway I've updated with block diagram

Comment: Relationships between users and the applicable power/zones/sites/applications, and possible a type indicator for users to indicate their level, sounds like it should work. It's possible to enforce consistency between the levels and relationships in the database, though complicated.

Comment: So I have to create relationships with all the power/zone/site...
And then in my code I'll have to use switch case for the different roles?

Comment: Are you asking how to design the tables or how to program the Java?

Comment: I was only wondering if there is another way to do that or it is the only solutions